# Configure hibernate's dialect using JNDI (with Spring)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jndi, dialect

I'm trying to configure a Spring+Hibernate web application using JNDI instead of a properties files. Everything works fine por database url, password, login, etc., but I can't get the dialect from the JNDI context.

I'm using this in my datatabase-context.xml:

```
<bean id="databaseUrl" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/url"/>
</bean>
<bean id="databaseDriver" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/driver"/>
</bean>
<bean id="databaseUsername" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/username"/>
</bean>
<bean id="databasePassword" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/password"/>
</bean>
<bean id="databaseDialect" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/dialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" ref="databaseDriver"/>
    <property name="url" ref="databaseUrl"/>
    <property name="username" ref=databaseUsername"/>
    <property name="password" ref="databasePassword"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">...</property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use the JNDI value for databaseDialect inside the `<prop name="hibernate.dialect">blabla</prop>` property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring can convert a `Map` to a `Properties` object, so you can do the following:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect">
                <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/dialect" />
            </entry>
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Reference:**

> Handles conversion from content `String`
>   to `Properties` object. Also handles `Map`
>   to `Properties` conversion, for
>   populating a `Properties` object via XML
>   "map" entries.

**Source: [`PropertiesEditor` javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/PropertiesEditor.html)**